# inertia Default layouts with passing props

Tags: reactjs, laravel, inertiajs

I have a laravel react project with inertia. I need to display data in the layout which I had previously done by wrapping every view in the Layout component but I need to pass the props to the layout every time.

```
export default function Show(props) {

    console.log(props);

    return (
        <Layout user={props.auth.user}>
            ...
        </Layout>
    );
}
```

I read about inertia default layouts, but can't figure out how to pass props to it.
Should I make an API call in the layout or stick to put every view inside Layout.

```
import Layout from './Layout'

createInertiaApp({
  resolve: name => {
    const pages = import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.jsx', { eager: true })
    let page = pages[`./Pages/${name}.jsx`]

    // API call and pass it to Layout below?
    page.default.layout = page.default.layout || (page => <Layout children={page} />)
    return page
  },
  // ...
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just an example (In Dashboard page)

```js
Dashboard.layout = (page: any) => {
    return <SystemProtectedLayout children={page} user={page.props.auth.user} />
}
```